# Is there a drawback for using too many Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm working on a tablet UI where everything is display in one screen. Basically, I have two main contents, one is a ListFragment, the other is the content. However, I need to display:

- Current location which updated dynamically.
- I also need to display a digital clock with current date and time.
- A timer displaying how long has passed since the app started.
- A tracker displaying number of item in the list and the current item being displayed, etc.

All these functions are being designed to stay in a separate location as well.

So right now I'm not sure if I put them into their own Fragment will it has any consequences against throwing them all inside one activity?

Comment: Since I don't know, I can't put it as an answer.  However, I'm 99% sure there's not a problem, and I'm 100% sure that the cut-off would be way more than 4 fragments if it would cause any problems.

Answer (score 1):

A `Fragment` should represent an independent behavior. All four of your points are either global attributes (i.e. current date/time, location, timer) or dependent on another `Fragment` (i.e. the currently selected list item). So it sounds like you want to group all four together into a single `Fragment`. Then implement a callback method to the activity which will update the currently selected list item number.

Comment: All four items position in corners of the screen and I have no authority to change that. So I want to make it as smooth as possible.